# Creating a rails view + controller that doesn't require a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, controller

I'm a bit confused on what's the proper design for a page that doesn't actually need a model.

As an example, I want to create an export page that will allow a user to export various other models into a CSV.

Obviously I'll need a view (most likely a `show.html.erb` file), and a controller; but making some sort of `Export` model wouldn't really make sense, and the same goes for creating new/edit/index views.

Is the correct way to do this just to manually create the view + controller for my Export page? It seems weird to not have a model after reading the rails documentation which is so heavily based on the MVC pattern, but I also don't see any reason why I "need" to follow the pattern for a case like this where a model just wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you are using the `scaffold` generator which *does* create a model.

If you just want to create the views and the controller type this in your terminal.

`rails g controller exports`

This will create the views, controller, and assets associated with the controller. Just add the routes.

`resources :exports`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a model.  The generators and assumptions in rails generally work better if you have a model, but you don't need one.   You can manually create the controllers and views, or use `rails g controller exports`.

You might look into form objects to provide a model in the controller - those are plain old ruby objects that provide a model without a database record.

A form object for an Export might start like this:

```
class Export
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `controller` in your `app/controllers` folder like this:

   ```
   class ExportsController < ApplicationController
     def show
       @export = ... # Your query here
     end 
   end
   ```
2. Create a folder named `exports` inside `app/views` folder.
3. Create your `show.html.erb` inside the `exports` folder you just created.
4. Add manually your `exports#show` route like this:

   ```
   resources "exports", only: [:show]
   ```

   You should be good to go. Add the necessary auth and before_action methods in your ExportsController.